# python method parameter annotation class

Tags: python, annotations

The following leads to an error on import because `Foo` is not yet defined:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, rhs: Foo):
        pass
```

Is there a way to annotate `rhs` to indicate it should be another instance of `Foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  Python has no way of declaring a class before you define it like in C++.

If you just want people to see that `rhs` should be a `Foo`, then you could always use a string literal:

```
def __init__(self, rhs: 'Foo'):
# or
def __init__(self, rhs: "<class '__main__.Foo'>"):
```

This makes your intent pretty clear and also allows you to have the annotation say whatever you want.

If however you want a real reference to the `Foo` class inside the `__annotations__` attribute of `Foo.__init__`, then you will need to manually alter this attribute after you define the class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, rhs):
        pass

Foo.__init__.__annotations__['rhs'] = Foo
print(Foo.__init__.__annotations__)
# {'rhs': <class '__main__.Foo'>}
```

But I personally would just use the first solution.  The primary purpose of function annotations is to document your functions.  Thus, a string literal that does this fulfills the purpose of the annotation.

Comment: Unfortunate, but I have to give you that one. I had tried the string-based annotation and didn't really like it for several reasons. I discuss this in a separate answer just in case others find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check in initializer:

```
 if ( not isinstance(rhs, Foo)):
    raise Exception('Not the right class!')
```